# Dismiss ViewController from TableViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have presented the viewController which contains a navigation controller whose view is loaded from another nib with the UITableView in it. I would like to dismiss that presented viewController from the UITableViewController. I have tried every combination of self.parentViewController and self.navigationController and self.navigationController.parentViewController but I am still not able to dismiss it. How and what is the best way for it to be dismissed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended up using delegates to dismiss the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I have never gotten `self.navigationController.parentViewController` to work as advertised, but this does work for me:

```
NSArray *viewControllerArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
int parentViewControllerIndex = [viewControllerArray count] - 2;
[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:parentViewControllerIndex] myParentViewMethod:arg1 withArg2:arg2 ...];
```

Comment: I could not get this to work, I only had one item in the array and that still did not dismiss the view. It may have to do with the way that I created it. I add a new UIViewController with XIB and create an outlet for a UINavigationController, I then hook that up. I next create a UITableViewController with XIB. Back in the UIViewController's XIB, I set it to load that new nib and set the class to the class of the UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController:animated:) not working?

```
[myViewController presentModalViewController:otherController animated:YES];
// ...
[myViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I need to process the data from the UITableView and am doing this inside the UITableViewController, I need to dismiss the parentViewController, but that does not work

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've painted yourself into a corner a bit with your hierarchy, but that's ok I think we can fix it.  There the two "usual" ways of doing this are:

1. From controller A, present controller B, from B do work, from B dismiss, return to A
2. From controller A, present controller B, from B do work, raise event via delegate protocol to A, from A dismiss B which returns control to A

In your current situation, this may require an uncomfortable ammount of refactoring, in which case it may be easier to just expose a handle to the other controller as a property, just make sure it's a weak reference like so:

```
@interface ControllerB : UIViewController
{
  ControllerA* controllerA;
}

@property (readwrite, nonatomic, assign) ControllerA* controllerA; // weak reference

@end
```

Or however you like, the point is to scope the variable properly so that it's available when you need it.